# if div contains text update another divs content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I have a `magento` website, I am trying to scan a table for a discount code and update another part of the table if a discount code is present.

The code I am using to try and achieve this is below:

```
    console.log("Discount Code Script Loaded");
$(function(){
    if($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text().replace(/\W/g, '')=="NathanTest9856"){
        console.log("Found code");
        $('span.price p').html("&pound;0.00");
        console.log("Shipping Total Corrected");
    } else{
        console.log("Coupon Code Not Found")
    }    
    console.log("Discount Code Script Completed");
});
console.log($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text().replace(/\W/g, ''));
```

the code of the page is simplified below:

```
<body>
  <div id="checkout-review-table-wrapper">
    <p>
      Discount Code (NathanTest9856)
    </p>
  </div>
<span class="price">
  <p>
     £15.00
 </p>
</span>
</body>
```

This can also be found in a jsfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/nlangerdevcenturion/qu6bvrc0/35/

The issue I seem to be facing is, it can't detect the Discount code of NathanTest9856 within the `p` tag.

As you can see from the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null at centurion.js:12`

Comment: your code is trying to compare`DiscountCodeNathanTest9856` with `NathanTest9856` put your code in a span and then fetch the details from it, here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu6bvrc0/43/) of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: The above "possible" duplicate doesn't include jquery `:contains` which seems to fit nicely in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery's `:contains` to check if an element contains something (in this case some text).

Change:

```
if($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text().replace(/\W/g, '')=="NathanTest9856"){
```

to:

```
if ($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p:contains("NathanTest9856")')) {
```

Updated code:

```js
console.log("Discount Code Script Loaded");
$(function() {
  if ($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p:contains("NathanTest9856")')) {
    console.log("**** Found code ****");
    $('span.price p').html("&pound;0.00");
    console.log("Shipping Total Corrected");
  } else {
    console.log("Coupon Code Not Found")
  }
  console.log("Discount Code Script Completed");
});
console.log($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text().replace(/\W/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="checkout-review-table-wrapper">
    <p>
      Discount Code (NathanTest9856)
    </p>
  </div>
  <span class="price">
  <p>
     £15.00
 </p>
</span>
</body>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qu6bvrc0/59/

Alternatively, you can use a multitude of vanilla javascript methods on `.text()`, see here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/2181514

eg:

```
if ($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text().indexOf("NathanTest9856")) >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the RegExp `/\W/g`. This will replace all non-word character (spaces in this case) and you'll remain with **DiscountCodeNathanTest9856** which is not equal to **NathanTest9856**

You could use a condition like this instead

```
/\(NathanTest9856\)/.test($('#checkout-review-table-wrapper p').text())
```

Which will check that paragraph's text for the existence of the **(NathanTest9856)** string.